# jni4net return error System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies

Tags: java, dll

I'm trying to import a `.DLL` into Java project by using jni4net.

Command I run: `proxygen [path_to_my_dll_file] -wd [directory_output_files]`

Command return error

```
System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///D:\Projects\UARTCommunicator\UARTCommunicator\Release\UARTCommunicator.dll' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.
File name: 'file:///D:\Projects\UARTCommunicator\UARTCommunicator\Release\UARTCommunicator.dll'
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadFrom(String assemblyFile, Evidence securityEvidence, Byte[] hashValue, AssemblyHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(String assemblyFile)
   at net.sf.jni4net.proxygen.model.Repository.LoadFile(String file)
   at net.sf.jni4net.proxygen.model.Repository.LoadAssemblies()
   at net.sf.jni4net.proxygen.model.Repository.Register()
   at net.sf.jni4net.proxygen.Program.Work(String[] args)
   at net.sf.jni4net.proxygen.Program.Main(String[] args)

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

I've done some researches and all of its said because different of platform x64 and x86 but I have checked again that my `.dll` file was built in x64.

- I also tested with JNA (Java Native Access), and it works. But now, I need to test my dll with jni4net (or normal JNI)
- I also try to use absolute path when run `proxygen` or use double backslash `\\` but none of them work

I'm new to Java and C++ with .dll. Can someone help please